# Creation Dashboard using WSO2 BAM already defined dashboards

Tags: wso2, dashboard, wso2-bam

I have question. I need to provide the report for my master work to compare BAM tools and one of them is  WSO2 BAM.I am beginner in it. I have to provide dashboards in WSO2BAM which will take information from my own database, from Oracle.  According to the theoretical introduction of WSO2BAM it has already defined dashboards and is it possible to configure it for my own database and how? and Is there some tutorials, some documentation or examples?

Answer (score 2):

Check under [user defined data in the BAM documentation](http://wso2.org/project/bam/1.3.0/docs/data_publishers.html). It should tell you how to do send custom events. After this is stored in the BAM database. You have to write a gadget and a data service or a back end component to pull out the data and display the data.

Comment: Thank you :)) But I have one more question about gadget creation: How can I make the result that gives created service of monitored server (the results) to put into the chart values?

Comment: So in a gadget, it's just like a html page constrained into a smaller place. Which means, you can use any web technology, i.e. html, java script and so forth. So you can just plugin some charting library, such as jqplot or any other and write a gadget. So, you will have to get the data exposed through some web service. More explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538885/creation-gadget-for-wso2-bam