# Creation Gadget for WSO2 BAM

Tags: wso2, dashboard, wso2-bam

I am creation Gadget for WSO2 BAM dashboard. I need to add the data to the chart that gives service of monitored server as result. How can I make this data as values of charts?

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to follow is,

1. You need to first expose this data through a service. Ex: Can be done through a data service with WSO2 DSS, a back end carbon component on top of WSO2 Carbon, or just any web service
2. Then, write a gadget to consume this service. Reference: [gadget tutorial](http://wso2.org/project/bam/1.3.0/docs/gadget_tutorial.html)

PS. There is a new BAM that will make all these things extremely easy, without having to write code. It should be available towards the end of the year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BAM2 alpha2 available in [here](http://dist.wso2.org/products/bam/2.0.0-alpha2/wso2bam-2.0.0-ALPHA2.zip) for generating gadgets according to your requirement. It is now much easier to generate a gadget with drag and drop gadget IDE comes with BAM2.

You can find more information from [documentation](http://dist.wso2.org/products/bam/2.0.0-alpha2/wso2bam-2.0.0-ALPHA2-docs.zip)

Answer (score 0):

This is available using GadgetGen tool feature under latest BAM version